# How to activate GPU in my kaggle notebook? It uses CPU 100% and GPU 0%. I need GPU accelerator for my deep learning project

Tags: deep-learning, kaggle

In kaggle I choose GPU accelerator when I am creating a note book. It then also shows CPU usage 100% and GPU usage 0%. Due to this, my code takes 8 hours execution time.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which libraries are you using?

Comment: sir iam using keras tensorflow libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation and which has been resolved. You can try doing the following since it worked for me.

1. Login to your kaggle account
   2.Go to your profile
2. Find the Account tab
3. Now verify your phone number.
4. Refresh, and boom!!!! accelerator option is available

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).